# Use serial CAN view programs over FT4232H

Tags: can, ftdi, firmware

I have a hardware device that has a FT4232H chip (FTDI chip that makes 4 virtual com ports). Simply put the device is able to speak certain protocols over the generated COM-ports (RS232, TTL, RS485, RS422). I would like to have the possibility to also use this device for CAN-diagnosing.
I would like to use it similarly to a [CANtact](https://cantact.io/cantact/users-guide.html) / [Canable](https://canable.io/) device. I want to use software like [Cangaroo](https://github.com/HubertD/cangaroo) / [CANtactapp](https://github.com/linklayer/cantact-app) or scripting using [python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

As I understand it aforementioned devices connect to a PC through USB and over the USB there is serial communication following the [LAWICEL-protocol](https://www.canusb.com/docs/can232_v3.pdf). A microcontrollerchip parses these commands and has a CAN-interface in hardware that speaks at TTL levels to a mcp2551 to interact with the CANbus.

The hardware/firmware is opensource but makes use of a USB-interface. I would like to integrate it in my device by using an existing VCP port of my FTDI chip (so I can use the existing USB connection.

Would there be some firmware available that does just this?
is it even possible like this or do I miss something?

I have the ability to add a processing chip like the STM32 and to flash it with firmware but I don't have the skills to change existing firmware.

Note: I don't want to use the FT4232 in MPSSE mode.